# Simple search filter is not working in ng-if angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using angularjs search filter, it's working fine but I want search box only in Cars list so I added `ng-if="key=='Cars'"` on search box so it will appear in cars only, but after adding `ng-if` filter stopped working, I'm not able to figureout why it isn't working?

```
<div class="form-group" ng-if="key=='Cars'">
 <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search in {{key}}" class="form-control input-sm" />
</div>
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    "Cars": ["Ferrari", "Lamborghini", "Mercedes", "BMW", "Audi", "Bugatti", "Ford"],
    "object": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    "object3": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4" ng-repeat="(key,val) in data">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">{{key}}</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group" ng-if="key=='Cars'">
              <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search in {{key}}" class="form-control input-sm" />
            </div>
            <table class="table">
              <tr ng-repeat="j in val | filter:search">
                <td>{{j}}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> There isn't any error in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your ng-if to `ng-show="key==='Cars'"`

Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shahzadadil/mabfzx0b/)

You can use this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shahzadadil/mabfzx0b/3/) as a solution. Maintain an array of search params respective to key. What is does is, it maintains a search param for each of the keys in your **data** object. It creates a new array called `search` in your `data`. And `$index` is the index of the parameter being used. For cars, it is 0, for object it would be 1 and so on. So, the textbox for cars will only update the corresponding search parameter bound to that, i.e. the value at 0th index. The other inputs, that are hidden are actually bound to values as 1st and 2nd index respectively. So there is no override of value.

Comment: This is just a css option, `ng-show` will only hide that `input`, I don't want it to be generate in DOM, I'm considering `css` as last option. and also  I want to know why this isn't working.

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/shahzadadil/mabfzx0b/2/  The value of the search parameter would never update, no matter what you enter into cars search box as the other 2 text boxes that are linked to search parameter are never rendered. So, the search parameter will always be empty and that is why it won't work.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Please refer to the updated fiddle in the original answer. I have updated it.

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Updated my answer with some explanation. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when filtering a list from a dropdown that displayed with ng-if. The problem is that ng-if creates a child scope, so in order to reach the list you need change to "ng-model="$parent.search"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `search` model to be global, then wrap your table inside `ng-if`

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    "Cars": ["Ferrari", "Lamborghini", "Mercedes", "BMW", "Audi", "Bugatti", "Ford"],
    "object": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    "object3": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  }
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4" ng-repeat="(key,val) in data">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">{{key}}</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group" ng-if="key=='Cars' || key=='object3'">
              <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search in {{key}}" class="form-control input-sm" />
              <table class="table">
                <tr ng-repeat="j in val | filter:search">
                  <td>{{j}}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-if="key!='Cars' && key!='object3'">
                <table class="table">
                <tr ng-repeat="j in val | filter:search">
                  <td>{{j}}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's filtering all columns  because you are creating global obj

Comment: In that case wrap your table inside ng-if, see my updated answer